# Declare a multivariate quotient ring in Julia

Tags: julia

I would like to declare the multivariate Ring $R[x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}]/(x_{2}^2-1, x_{1}^{3}x_{3}-2)$. It would be very helpful if there is some method to do this for an arbitrary number of variables.

Thank you so much,

Comment: It helps others help you if you can give a bit of context to your question as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Does the Ring you mention is related to https://nemocas.github.io/AbstractAlgebra.jl/latest/mpolynomial_rings/ ?

Comment: Sadly [SO] does not support math formatting (MathJax). Use [CodeGogs](https://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?{R[x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}]}/{(x_{2}^2-1,&space;x_{1}^{3}x_{3}-2)}) to convert into image.

Answer (score 3):

I think [AbstractAlgebra.jl](https://github.com/Nemocas/AbstractAlgebra.jl) is a very good fit for this. You can call it like:

```
julia> using AbstractAlgebra

julia> ring = ZZ
Integers

julia> S, (x, y, z) = PolynomialRing(ring, ["x", "y", "z"])
(Multivariate Polynomial Ring in x, y, z over Integers, AbstractAlgebra.Generic.MPoly{BigInt}[x, y, z])

julia> p1 = y^2 - 1
xy^2 - 1

julia> p2 = x^3 * z - 2
x^3*z - 2

julia> div(3 * (x^2 + y^3) * p1 + p2, p1)
3*x^2 + 3*y^3

julia> div(3 * (x^2 + y^3) * p1 + p2, p2)
1
```

And sorry if this doesn't answer your question, my mathematics is not that good. For more information, please visit the [documentation](https://nemocas.github.io/AbstractAlgebra.jl/latest/mpolynomial_rings/).

Comment: Unfortunately general quotient rings are not available in AbstractAlgebra just yet. In fact, the package you want is Singular.jl which will use a Groebner basis implementation to do this. I am however not certain if Singular's quotient rings are fully available in Singular.jl. I will try to find this out for you. Very likely there is also a restriction to R being a field.

Comment: My colleagues tell me it is now (just) available in Oscar.jl, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

According to my colleagues this is available in Oscar.jl [1] (which is built on Singular and AbstractAlgebra.jl, mentioned by @aahlback and myself in another answer).

The documentation is in the process of being written right now, so keep an eye on the package to see how this can be done in the very near future.

The implementation is in [2] if you want to take a look.

Edit: there looks to be a relevant example here [3]. Note the ring R in that example is a polynomial ring and does not correspond to your R.

For the coefficient ring (your R) you can currently use any field, Z or Z/nZ, according to the maintainer of the Singular project (which Oscar.jl uses for these computations). It's very, very hard to extend this to other rings.

[1] https://github.com/oscar-system/Oscar.jl/

[2] https://github.com/oscar-system/Oscar.jl/blob/master/src/Rings/MPolyQuo.jl

[3] https://oscar-system.github.io/Oscar.jl/dev/CommutativeAlgebra/ca/#Example-24

Answer (score 0):

let

```
julia> using Oscar 

julia> R,(x,y,z)=PolynomialRing(QQ,["x" , "y","z"])
(Multivariate Polynomial Ring in x, y, z over Rational Field, fmpq_mpoly[x, y, z])

julia> I=ideal(R,[y^2-1, x^3*z^3-2]) 
  ideal(y^2 - 1, x^3*z^3 - 2)

julia> S,_=quo(R,I)
  (Quotient of Multivariate Polynomial Ring in x, y, z over Rational 
 Field by ideal(y^2 - 1, x^3*z^3 - 2), Map from Multivariate Polynomial Ring in x, y, z over Rational Field to S defined by a julia-function with inverse)
```

You could verify if p=y^2-1 is an element of the ideal I.

```
 julia>p=y^2 - 1
 y^2 - 1

 julia>R(p)==0
 false

 julia>S(p)==0
 true
```

You could also define a polynomial with many variables this way.

```
julia> R,q,z=PolynomialRing(QQ, "x" => 1:2, "q" => 1:3,"z" => 1:4)
(Multivariate Polynomial Ring in 9 variables x_{1}, x_{2}, q_{1}, q_{2}, ..., z_{4} over Rational Field, fmpq_mpoly[x_{1}, x_{2}], fmpq_mpoly[q_{1}, q_{2}, q_{3}], fmpq_mpoly[z_{1}, z_{2}, z_{3}, z_{4}])
```